# GCDAsyncUdpSocket Multicast Gets HTTP 412 Response

Tags: objective-c, ios, http, udp, gcdasyncsocket

I am building a iOS application that sends out a multicast message (SSDP) and listens for responses from devices that implement that protocol. I am using GCDAsyncUdpSocket to create the UDP socket to broadcast the SSDP message and receive responses. The problem that I am having is that the message the application receives from the all of the devices on the network is the same: a `HTTP 412` response.

Here is my code:

**Initialize socket**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:0 error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error binding: %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error receiving: %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }

    [udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error enableing broadcast: %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Socket Created");
}
```

**Create Socket**

```
- (IBAction)socketFind:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN: \"ssdp discover\"\r\nMX: 3\r\nST: ssdp:all\r\nUSER-AGENT: iOS UPnP/1.1 TestApp/1.0\r\n\r\n"];
    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"239.255.255.250" port:1900 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];

    NSLog(@"Sent Data");
}
```

**Data Received Callback**

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Data");
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (msg)
    {
        NSLog(@"Message: %@",msg);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *host = nil;
        uint16_t port = 0;
        [GCDAsyncUdpSocket getHost:&host port:&port fromAddress:address];

        NSLog(@"Unknown Message: %@:%hu", host, port);
    }
}
```

When the `didReceiveData` function is called, I get the following message:

```
Message: HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed

Connection:close

CONTENT-LENGTH:0
```

Comment: Found the problem. The issue was located in the M-Search string, specifically the `ssdp discover` portion. The string needed to be `ssdp:discover`. The colon between the KVP was missing and that's why it blew up.

Comment: Thanks for this :
[GCDAsyncUdpSocket getHost:&host port:&port fromAddress:address];
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was with the M-Search string. I was missing the colon between `sspd` and `discover`. If you are getting a `412` response, I would make sure that you are formatting everything correctly. Turns out, that was my issue...